# Insert a newline character every 14 numbers using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using Python, I need to insert a newline character after every 14 numbers. `str1` is of string type.

It was a file with variable spaces which I converted to a string, removed excess spaces using
 `' '.join(mystring.split())` and I am trying to write it back in a file.

An example of `str1` is like:

```
str1 = "000009.26+151754.5 0.038605 15.298476 1.1986 19.921 0.042 19.811 0.036 19.386 0.017 19.165 0.023 19.323 0.069 -1.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -25.085 000009.38+135618.4 0.039088 13.938447 2.2400 19.218 0.026 18.893 0.022 18.445 0.018 18.331 0.024 18.110 0.033 -1.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -27.419 000009.42-102751.9 0.039269 -10.464428 1.8442 19.249 0.036 19.029 0.027 18.980 0.021 18.791 0.018 18.751 0.047 0.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -26.459"
```

Is there a pythonic way to split this after every 14 numbers, so that I can write it back in a file (1st row = 14 numbers, 2nd row = 14 numbers, etc)

Comment: Thanks for editing, Casimir et Hippolyte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP wants to have 14 numbers per line and not 14 digits per line

```
str_list = str1.split()
num = len(str_list)
all_lines = [str_list[i:i+14] for i in range(0, num, 14)]
all_lines = [" ".join(line)+"\n" for line in all_lines]
fp = open("outfile.txt", 'w')
fp.writelines(all_lines)
fp.close()
```

Of course, some of the above can be combined to bring down the # of lines, but that would make the code harder to read.

Comment: That worked perfectly, @Raghuram Onti Srinivasan. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, to remove spaces from a string I would use this code

```
mystring = "000009.26+151754.5  2349..."

new_string = mystring.replace(" ","")
print new_string
```

Then, I would set up a loop until you hit the end of the string

```
i = 0 
while i < len(new_string):
    segment = new_string[i:i+14]
    print segment #write segment to the new file here
    i = i + 14
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply, @Polka Dancer. When I mentioned that I had to remove the spaces, I alreay succeeded in doing so. I have the str2 right now, and I would it to be divided into 14 numbers per row. Like, 1st row would be 000009.26+151754.5 0.038605 ... -25.085. The second row would be 000009.38+135618.4 ... -27.419 and so on. I am sorry if I was not clear in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions you can do something like

```
import re
str1 = "000009.26+151754.5 0.038605 15.298476 1.1986 19.921 0.042 19.811 0.036 19.386 0.017 19.165 0.023 19.323 0.069 -1.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -25.085 000009.38+135618.4 0.039088 13.938447 2.2400 19.218 0.026 18.893 0.022 18.445 0.018 18.331 0.024 18.110 0.033 -1.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -27.419 000009.42-102751.9 0.039269 -10.464428 1.8442 19.249 0.036 19.029 0.027 18.980 0.021 18.791 0.018 18.751 0.047 0.000 -9.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 -26.459"
str2 = re.sub(r"((\S+\s){14})", r"\1\n", str1)
print str2
```

the \S+\s part matches a string of nonwhite space characters followed by a whitespace character.

the xxx{14} part matches 14 strings of xxx

The \1\n part takes what was found in the regular expression, and tacks on a newline to it

The parentheses are used to hold the matches values, so you can access them with \1, \2, \3, etc in the substitution part.